# How can I force the deletion of a session ID cookie with express-session?

Tags: node.js, session, express, cookies, express-session

I'm using the express-session module to set a session with an expiration age. After this age, the cookie will be deleted when the page is refreshed. However, such as when the user logs out, I would like to forcefully delete the cookie. I have already successfully destroyed the session using `req.session.destroy.`

I've tried to use:

```
res.clearCookie('SID').status(200).send('Page');
```

inside `req.session.destroy,` although, if I view the cookie details in the browser I see that the content is set to nothing, and the expiration date is set to `Thursday, 1 January 1970 at 01:00:00,` although the cookie will not delete itself. I also set `unset: 'destroy'` inside the session store config, but this did not solve my issue.

Middleware:

```
app.use(session({
  store: new MemoryStore({
    checkPeriod: 86400000
  }),
  cookie: {
    secure: true,
    maxAge: 10000
  },
  secret: secret,
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  name: 'SID',
  unset: 'destroy'
}));
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to force to set the values of `req.session.cookie.expires` or `req.session.cookie.maxAge`.

See this peiece of code as an example,

```
var timeInMillseconds = 3600000;
req.session.cookie.expires = new Date(Date.now() + timeInMillseconds);
req.session.cookie.maxAge = timeInMillseconds;
```

Use this middleware for now

```
app.use(session({
  secret: 'mySecre',
  saveUninitialized: true
}))

app.get('/', function(req, res){
   req.session.myUser = "myUser";
   req.session.cookie.expires = new Date(Date.now() + 36000000);
   req.session.cookie.myDog = "myDog";
   res.status(201).send(req.session); //you can also use 200
   console.log(req.session);
})
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for trying to help. I did req.session.cookie.expires = new Date(0); but this does not even seem to set the expiration date on the cookie, it just remains at the default set in the config.

Comment: try the exact code up there, with `new Date(Date.now() + hour)` also are you using `req.session.save(function(err) {})` for the client to save it? @MatthewChristopher

Comment: Hour is not defined. I'm also not setting the session like that, in express-session, I'm setting it like this: req.session.user = value;

Comment: Sorry, this still isn't working. I'm using req.session.cookie.expires = new Date(Date.now() + 3600000); It wouldnt be req.session.user.cookie.expires would it?

Comment: Also, the expiration cant be set right as when I view the cookie info the expiration is what I've set it to in the express-session config, not an hour ahead.

Comment: what do you get when log `req.session` and `req.cookies` ? also can you put your middleware code, for session configs @MatthewChristopher

Comment: Looks like nothing is being logged. See my question for middleware.

Comment: hmm, this is interesting. let's figure out the problem now. can you check my update and try it out @MatthewChristopher

Comment: also try to use `originalMaxAge` instead of `maxAge`, let's see what happens @MatthewChristopher

Comment: I'll be able to check in the morning, thanks a lot for helping.

Comment: thank you too, please let me know @MatthewChristopher

Comment: Hi, I've done what you've asked. Since no resave option is deprecated, I tested with both true and false - they both gave the same output: in the browser: {"cookie":{"originalMaxAge":36000000,"expires":"2017-09-09T17:40:19.051Z","httpOnly":true,"path":"/"},"myUser":"myUser"} and in the console: Session {
  cookie:
   { path: '/',
     _expires: 2017-09-09T17:40:19.053Z,
     originalMaxAge: 36000000,
     httpOnly: true,
     myDog: 'myDog' },
  myUser: 'myUser' }

Comment: I suggest we need to use resave: true because: if it does not implement the touch method and your store sets an expiration date on stored sessions, then you likely need resave: true

Comment: please refer to https://hastebin.com/kefixuqota.js for more information